# Very confused: Is spring-boot-starter-web req'd to use Spring Boot with gRPC

Tags: spring-boot, grpc

I am trying to use the [LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter/) to test using Spring Boot with gRPC. It seems like all the Spring Boot/gRPC examples have the **spring-boot-starter-web** module included in the build. Is that starter module required in order for the server class annotated with *@GRpcService* to be always active when started as a Spring Boot jar?

Thanks very much,

Steve

Comment: Ok, according to https://www.codenotfound.com/grpc-spring-boot-example.html, "We include the spring-boot-starter-web dependency which automatically sets up an embedded Apache Tomcat that will host our gRPC service endpoint." I guess I got my answer.

Comment: Also note that most starters are starters of starters. Opinionated ways to get the basics running with minimal configuration. They are the core of spring boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. From [codenotfound](https://www.codenotfound.com/grpc-spring-boot-example.html)

> We include the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency which
>   automatically sets up an embedded Apache Tomcat that will host our
>   gRPC service endpoint.